# Syslog rotation using log4cplus appender MaxFileSize and MaxBackupIndex

Tags: linux, config, syslog, log4cplus

I have below config, which seems to have no effect on the rotation of the syslog:

> log4cplus.appender.syslog=log4cplus::SysLogAppender
> log4cplus.appender.syslog.MaxFileSize=200KB
>
> log4cplus.appender.syslog.MaxBackupIndex=5
> log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
> log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%T] %-5p %b %x -
> %m%n

I would like to be able to manage syslog size and number of the backups.
What would be correct way of doing this using Log4Cplus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SysLogAppender` appender is sending to OS syslog. It has no control over the rotation. That is for you to set up using your syslog implementation configuration.